# SQL : Get the duration between start DateTime and End DateTime from Table entries

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, datetime

I have a SQL table which has entries of machine start and end time (DateTime) with duration of machine running. Given a start DateTime and End DateTime I want to calculate the duration for which machine was running. DB is SQL and Code is in C#.

Note: THere might be some duration when the machine is not running in between the given start and end DateTime, I want to ignore that duration during the total calculation.

Consider example

| Start Time Machine | End Time Machine | Duration(Mins) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1:00:01 | 2:00:00 | - 60 |
| 2:00:01 | 2:30:00 | - 30 |
| 3:00:01 | 4:00:00 | - 60 |

If the selected Start time is 1:40:00  and End time is 3:20:00( **notice that machine did not run from 2:30:00 to 3:00)**

**how to get the duration in SQL?**

For above example the answer should be 70 mins.

```
1:40:00 to 2:30:00 - 50Mins
3:00:00 to 3:20:00 - 20Mins
Total = 70mins  between 1:40:00 and 3:20:00
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Better to do in c#.  The SQL query becomes complicated.

Comment: @jdweng it's a simple query in sql , see my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can do it , I wrote in sql server (assuming you are in microsoft  eco system) but you can do the same thing in any other dbms)

```
select sum(datediff(minute, case when startdate <@startdate then @startdate else startdate end,case when enddate < @enddate then enddate else @enddate end))
from cte
where @startdate <= enddate and @enddate >= startdate
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=386216df04ea63255c81f710f72ff3a1)*

in postgresql you can just do this :

```
select extract( epoch from sum(case when enddate < enddatevar then enddate else enddatevar end - case when startdate <startdatevar then startdatevar else startdate end)) /60 
from cte
where startdatevar <= enddate and enddatevar >= startdate
```

Comment: DATEDIFF isnt available in PostgreSQL, How can i do the same thing in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @LetsCode see updated answer , that should work ( if I didn't get any mistake)

Comment: Consider, one more entry with start time and end time is null (Machine is still running)
In the above scenario this entry will not be considered, 
Is it possible to consider this entry with end time as current time ? If yes, How to do it?

Comment: @LetsCode in the smae query wherever end date is null replace it with currentdate :
`coalesce(endate , now())`

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can do:

```
 SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, EndTime,StartTime)) FROM table_name
```

Or, in C#, assuming you get a collection of objects with `StartTime` and `EndTime` properties:

```
var duration = results.Sum(x => x.EndTime.Subtract(x.StartTime).TotalMinutes);
```